# Triangles when baking normal

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I usually don't bake normal maps often so I might be doing something completely wrong.

I want to bake the normals from a high poly mesh to low poly but I always get these triangles when I bake using 'selected to active' in the resulting normal map.

I've gone from a high poly mesh and simply made a new low poly by outlining/tracing the high poly with way less polygons. I have also separated the uv-island so no overlapping is done as I heard that could be a problem.

I've tried with diffrent ray distance settings

Is the distance to between the meshes to large? 
Do the mesh has to bear more resemblens to the high poly? 
Do the low poly mesh have to originate from the high poly in some way? 
Does it matter if the low poly is underneath or over the high poly?

Any help would be appreciated

[image: Setup]
[image: Resulting Map]

Comment: Your setup looks ok. Maybe your Hi-poly has duplicate faces or is non-manifold ? Does it works with 2.79 ?
"Is the distance to between the meshes to large?" > No
"Do the mesh has to bear more resemblens to the high poly?" > No
"Do the low poly mesh have to originate from the high poly in some way?" > No 
"Does it matter if the low poly is underneath or over the high poly?" > the hi poly must be inward (below normals)

Comment: You are correct, I double checked the geometry of the high poly mesh and it was non-manifold and to be honest a total mess, it was imported straight from marvelous designer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

If anyone has similar problems the problem is very likely due a non-manifold geometry with the Hi-poly mesh which can cause these artifacts.

The geometry of this Hi-poly mesh was non-manifold, contained duplicated vertices and was a topological nightmare on closer inspection.

By fixing the geometry I could bake the normal map without any problems.

Comment: Thanks! You're the real MVP